# Magento 2: color picker is not working in ui custom form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, magento2.4.2, ui-form, magento2.4.0

[image]

it's show like this and I define its field name
in XML file [image]

Comment: you can refer https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-colorpicker.html

Comment: just use same code in your form

Comment: i can use this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-colorpicker.html but still face same problem